# In a search box,how to display data from two different columns of a same database table depending on the input?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using a inputbox to search data from the database. Whenver I type something in input box,I get relative data predictions from only column A and I want the predictions from column A and column B, if a match is found with input given.If I type data from the column B,then in prediction I get Value of Column A for that particular row.Both the columns are from same table.So,please help..
HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" ng-model="assignName" id="assignName" placeholder="Assigned To" class="form-control" min-length="4" uib-typeahead="as.aName as as.aName for as in assign($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false">
    <input type="hidden" id="assignId" value="{{assignName.aId}}"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.assign = function(assignName) {
      if (assignName.length >= 2) {
          return servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Activity/search_query.php', {
              'assignName': assignName,
              'case': 'getAssign' 
          }).then(function(response) {

              var res = _.map(response, function(value, key, list) {
                  var obj = {
                      'aName': '',
                      'aId': '',
                      'aFname':''
                  };
                  obj.aName = value.user_name;
                  obj.aId = value.id;
                  obj.aFname = value.first_name;
                  return obj;
              });
              return res;
          });
      }
  };
```

PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT
users.id,
users.first_name,
users.user_name
FROM
users
WHERE
(users.first_name LIKE '$assignName%' OR users.user_name LIKE '$assignName%')";
```

[image: Sample output1]

If I enter data from column A..then the predictions are from table A itself.

[image: Sample Outpu2]

If I enter data from Column B,I get data from Column A only having the same row...And I want from column B.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning whole object. Try using filters to return the specific object relating to typed word:

Something like:

```
$scope.assign = function(assignName) {
      if (assignName.length >= 2) {
          return servicePOST.send(appConstants.BASE_MS_URL + 'Activity/search_query.php', {
              'assignName': assignName,
              'case': 'getAssign' 
          }).then(function(response) {

              var res = _.map(response, function(value, key, list) {
                  var obj = {
                      'aName': '',
                      'aId': '',
                      'aFname':''
                  };
                  obj.aName = value.user_name;
                  obj.aId = value.id;
                  obj.aFname = value.first_name;
                  //here $ means search all the properties of object
                  return $filter('filter')(obj , {'$': assignName});
              });
              return res;
          });
      }
  };
```

And your HTML to:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" ng-model="assignName" id="assignName" placeholder="Assigned To" class="form-control" min-length="4" uib-typeahead="as for as in assign($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false">
```

Comment: can you `console.log(res)` before the return and tell me the output??

Comment: @Harsha how about `console.log($filter('filter')(obj , {'$': assignName}))`